# How to loop a promise in for loop and break if condition met

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, protractor

I am new to using Promise and breaking my head to solve this. I want to run a script until a condition is met in protractor with below code but it's not working. how to fix this?

```
let counter = 30;
for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

  browser.executeScript(somescript).then((value) => {
    //console.log(value);
    if (value > 0) 
      //do some stuff
    }
    else {
      return; //exit for loop --not working
       //or
      i=counter;// to exit if i and counter value same
    }
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this `limitedRetry` code that would appear to be what you need

```
limitedRetry = (cont, fn) => fn().catch(err => cont > 0 ? limitedRetry(cont - 1, fn) : Promise.reject(err));
```

Your use would be

```
limitedRetry(30, function() {
    browser.executeScript(somescript).then((value) => {
        if (value > 0) {
            // do some stuff
            return 'this will be the resolved value of the promise';
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('try again');
        }
    });
})
.then(v => console.log(v))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Remark: this assumes `somescript` is always the same. (@JaromandaX thats true).

Comment: true: but I can't see in the code in the question why it wouldn't be

Comment: @Karthi I think this could be what you need. So I deleted my answer.

Comment: Note: this code retries 30 times, so it could try 31 times in total, change `cont > 0` to `cont > 1` or pass in 29 instead of 30 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you. can you provide it in typescript? I was not able to fix compilation issues to match typescript syntax.

Comment: oh, there's a typescript tag in your question, but no typescript code ... sorry, I don't "typescript"

Answer (score 0):

Now you're firing all `executeScript`s at the same time, and in the worst case the last script (result) may return first. You should start the next `executeScript` only if you have the result of the previous `executeScript`.

This can be done by 'listening' to the result of the previous promise, and calling `executeScript` after you know what the previous result was. I've replaced `somescript` with the variable `i`, so that the result is more determinate. In case you're just looking for a retry, see the other answer.

```js
var browser = {
    executeScript: function(i) {
        return Promise.resolve(i);
    }
}

var initial = Promise.resolve(null);
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    (function(locali) { 
        initial = initial.then(function(prev) {
            if(prev === undefined) return;

            return browser.executeScript(locali).then(function (value) {
                console.log(value);

                if (value < 5) {
                    return value;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    })(i);
}
```